# Server-based Microsoft Office to PDF Converters?

Tags: linux, pdf, ms-office, server-side

I'm looking to convert our library of MS Office files into PDFs on a Linux server. What I'm looking for is similar to [this](http://www.ajaxdocumentviewer.com/servicespdf.asp).

Anyone know of one not so costly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/) is free, it uses OpenOffice to do the conversion. Unfortunately OpenOffice doesn't import MS Office files perfectly so YMMV. Another option is to use [OfficeToPDF](http://www.cognidox.com/opensource/officetopdf), this is however an Windows application that requires Office to be installed. You could probably solve this by running Windows in a virtual machine on your server and remotely control it.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider [Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/index.html), [Aspose.Cells for Java](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/aspose.cells-for-java/index.html), [Aspose.Slides for Java](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/aspose.slides-for-java/index.html); these components can convert Microsoft Word, Excel and Powerpoint files to PDF on Linux.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.